# Arguments tab missing in eclipse buildship plugin

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

'Aguments' tab is not visible in 'run configuration' in eclipse.

steps to reproduce:
create build.gradle file
click 'run as' drop down -> run configuration -> select gradle task -> click 'new' on top right

this will  create 'new_configuration' and these tabs should be visible.
eclipse version is 2020-12
[image]

[image]

I want to see 'arguments' tab beside 'common' tab. also few other tabs are missing like java
below image contains everything , but I am seeing only above picture situation.

[image]

How to  bring 'java', and 'Arguments' Tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***Java Home*** tab and the ***Arguments*** tab has been **removed to avoid redundancy with the *Project Settings* tab** in Eclipse Buildship 3.0, which has been [released December 5, 2018](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship/releases/3.0.0).

[Donát Csikós gives the following explanation in the description of the pull request](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/pull/810#issue-233639193):

> I've removed arguments and java home tabs from the run configuration
> dialog as it provided duplicate functionality.

See [commit aa57553](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/commit/aa57553ebfa7a1a62889703286c8fbee6f249c0e#diff-7d2562a53822097aca683bbe36f00f96fa36dc206dda85800ddc67ae986c61a6) of [pull request #810](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/pull/810).